# wordpress, nginx and rewriting a url

Tags: wordpress, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm running wordpress on nginx with fastcgi. Wordpress permalinks are all working fine but I have one particular url which I need to present better (particularly for social sharing of the page).

I want the url /competitions/tables/?competition=1234 to display as /competitions/tables/1234

Also, i want the user to be able to navigate to /competitions/tables/1234 and the page display properly.

From a wordpress perspective, I have the "competitions" url part created using custom page template and the same for the "tables" url part.

Any advice here would be great. Tis driving me mad at this stage.

Thanks,
Mick.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the best solution but it can be a quick fix.
Note: this will only work for the competitor 1234.

**To do**

- In the admin, create a page/post/cpt called 1234 that have the page "table" as parent (same as you have done for competition and tables)
- Create a new template: single-1234.php + html/functions etc
- Inside your "table" template, read the url and if the competition argument = 1234 redirect the user to the "/competitions/tables/1234" url

Comment: Thanks Romain but the solution is too static. I have hundreds of these tables so I need a solution thats more dynamic.

Comment: Same problem from a different perspective, is it possible to make a request to /competitions/table/1234 (1234 is the id which is dynamic) which is mapped to my custom wordpress php page which would extract the id (1234 in this case) and display as /competitions/table/1234 ?

Comment: You got the idea =)
Here is the solution http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/custom-page-template-page-based-on-url-rewrite--wp-30564.
Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
rewrite ^/competitions/tables(.*)$ /competitions/tables/$arg_competition? permanent;
```